# PostgreSQL Select join table and a function

Tags: postgresql

I got a function in my database, that returns a table. What I'm trying to do is select joining a table and that function.
I saw that it can't be done in the FROM place, but if I put the function in the select it takes too long to execute.
My SQL is:

```
select
    "Grades"."id",
    SUPRIMENTO_LOJA("Grades"."id", 30, 1, 1)
from
    "Grades"
```

This takes more than 500s to execute

I tried this too but it returns an error

```
select
    *
from
    "Grades",
    SUPRIMENTO_LOJA("Grades"."id", 30, 1, 1)
```

Whats the best way to make this select to work?

EDIT:
The function is this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION suprimento_loja(grade_id integer, vendas_dias integer, lojaId integer, embalagem numeric(15, 4)) 
RETURNS TABLE(qtd integer, maximo integer, ultFornecedor character varying(50), 
ultCompra character varying(10), ultVenda character varying(10), classeLoja character varying(1), 
vendas integer, sugestao integer, giroLoja numeric(15, 4))
AS $$
DECLARE     
    qtde1 integer;
    vendasdiae1 integer;
    maximoe1 integer;
    ultvendae1 timestamp;
    ultcomprae1 timestamp;
    ultforne1 varchar(50);
    classee1 varchar(1);
    vendase1 integer;
    qtde2 integer;
    vendasdiae2 integer;
    maximoe2 integer;
    ultvendae2 timestamp;
    ultcomprae2 timestamp;
    ultforne2 varchar(50);
    vendase2 integer;
    qtde3 integer;
    vendasdiae3 integer;
    maximoe3 integer;
    ultvendae3 timestamp;
    ultcomprae3 timestamp;
    ultforne3 varchar(50);
    vendase3 integer;
    giroe1 numeric(15, 4);
    giroe2 numeric(15, 4);
    giroe3 numeric(15, 4);
BEGIN
    with vendas as (
    select
        sum(coalesce("quantidade", 0)) as vendas_periodo,
        "inventario_id"
    from
        "WVItens"
    where
        "WVItens"."ultimoDownload" between current_timestamp - (select to_interval(vendas_dias))
        and current_timestamp and coalesce("status", '') = ''
    group by
        "inventario_id")
    select into qtde1, vendasdiae1, maximoe1, ultvendae1, ultcomprae1, ultforne1, classee1, vendase1, giroe1
        cast("quantidadeAtual" as integer), 
        cast("vendasPorDia" as integer), 
        cast("maximoEmDias" as integer), 
            "dataUltimaVenda", 
        "dataUltimaCompra", 
        "ultimoFornecedor", 
        "classe", 
        cast(vendas_periodo as integer),
        coalesce("giro", 0)
    from 
        "Inventarios", 
        "Lojas",
        vendas
    where 
                "Inventarios"."estoque_id" = "Lojas"."estoque1_id" and 
        coalesce("Inventarios"."status", '') = '' and
        "Inventarios"."id" = vendas."inventario_id" and
        "Lojas"."id" = lojaId and 
        "grade_id" = gradeId;

    with vendas as (
    select
        sum(coalesce("quantidade", 0)) as vendas_periodo,
        "inventario_id"
    from
        "WVItens"
    where
        "WVItens"."ultimoDownload" between current_timestamp - (select to_interval(vendas_dias))
        and current_timestamp and coalesce("status", '') = ''
    group by
        "inventario_id")        
    select into qtde2, vendasdiae2, maximoe2, ultvendae2, ultcomprae2, ultforne2, vendase2, giroe2
        cast("quantidadeAtual" as integer), 
        cast("vendasPorDia" as integer), 
        cast("maximoEmDias" as integer), 
        "dataUltimaVenda", 
        "dataUltimaCompra", 
        "ultimoFornecedor", 
        cast(vendas_periodo as integer),
        coalesce("giro", 0)
    from 
        "Inventarios", 
                "Lojas",
            vendas
    where 
        "Inventarios"."estoque_id" = "Lojas"."estoque2_id" and 
        coalesce("Inventarios"."status", '') = '' and
        "Inventarios"."id" = vendas."inventario_id" and
        "Lojas"."id" = lojaId and 
        "grade_id" = gradeId;   

    with vendas as (
    select
        sum(coalesce("quantidade", 0)) as vendas_periodo,
        "inventario_id"
    from
        "WVItens"
    where
        "WVItens"."ultimoDownload" between current_timestamp - (select to_interval(vendas_dias))
        and current_timestamp and coalesce("status", '') = ''
    group by
        "inventario_id")            
    select into qtde3, vendasdiae3, maximoe3, ultvendae3, ultcomprae3, ultforne3, vendase3, giroe3
        cast("quantidadeAtual" as integer), 
        cast("vendasPorDia" as integer), 
        cast("maximoEmDias" as integer), 
        "dataUltimaVenda", 
        "dataUltimaCompra", 
        "ultimoFornecedor", 
        cast(vendas_periodo as integer),
        coalesce("giro", 0)
    from 
        "Inventarios", 
        "Lojas",
        vendas
    where 
        "Inventarios"."estoque_id" = "Lojas"."estoque2_id" and 
        coalesce("Inventarios"."status", '') = '' and
        "Inventarios"."id" = vendas."inventario_id" and
        "Lojas"."id" = lojaId and 
        "grade_id" = gradeId;   

    qtd := 0;
    IF (qtde1 is not null) THEN
        qtd := qtd + qtde1;
    END IF; 
    IF (qtde2 is not null) THEN
        qtd := qtd + qtde2;
    END IF; 
    IF (qtde3 is not null) THEN
        qtd := qtd + qtde3;
    END IF;         

    giroLoja = (giroe1 + giroe2 + giroe3) / 3;

    maximo := 0;
    IF ((maximoe1 is not null) and (vendasdiae1 is not null)) THEN
        maximo := maximo + (maximoe1 * vendasdiae1);
    END IF;
    IF ((maximoe2 is not null) and (vendasdiae2 is not null)) THEN
        maximo := maximo + (maximoe2 * vendasdiae2);
    END IF;
    IF ((maximoe3 is not null) and (vendasdiae3 is not null)) THEN
        maximo := maximo + (maximoe3 * vendasdiae3);
    END IF;

    IF (qtde1 is null) THEN
        qtde1 := 0;
    END IF; 
    IF (qtde2 is null) THEN
        qtde2 := 0;        
    END IF; 
    IF (qtde3 is null) THEN
        qtde3 := 0;        
    END IF; 
    IF (maximoe1 is null) THEN
        maximoe1 := 0;        
    END IF; 
    IF (maximoe2 is null) THEN
        maximoe2 := 0;
    END IF; 
    IF (maximoe3 is null) THEN
        maximoe3 := 0;                        
    END IF; 
    IF (vendasdiae1 is null) THEN
        vendasdiae1 := 0;                
    END IF; 
    IF (vendasdiae2 is null) THEN
        vendasdiae2 := 0;
    END IF; 
    IF (vendasdiae3 is null) THEN
        vendasdiae3 := 0;                                
    END IF; 
    IF (vendase1 is null) THEN
        vendase1 := 0;                        
    END IF; 
    IF (vendase2 is null) THEN
        vendase2 := 0;
    END IF; 
    IF (vendase3 is null) THEN
        vendase3 := 0;  
    END IF; 

    ultCompra := '';
    ultVenda := '';
    ultFornecedor := '';


    IF (ultcomprae1 is null) THEN
        IF (ultcomprae2 is null) THEN
            IF (ultcomprae3 is not null) THEN
                ultCompra := cast(extract(day from ultcomprae3) || '/' || extract(month from ultcomprae3) || '/' || extract(year from ultcomprae3) as varchar(10));
                ultFornecedor := ultforne3;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF ((ultcomprae3 is null) or (ultcomprae2 > ultcomprae3)) THEN
                ultCompra := cast(extract(day from ultcomprae2) || '/' || extract(month from ultcomprae2) || '/' || extract(year from ultcomprae2) as varchar(10));
                ultFornecedor := ultforne2;
            ELSE
                ultCompra := cast(extract(day from ultcomprae3) || '/' || extract(month from ultcomprae3) || '/' || extract(year from ultcomprae3) as varchar(10));
                ultFornecedor := ultforne3;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        IF ((ultcomprae2 is null) or (ultcomprae1 > ultcomprae2)) THEN
            IF ((ultcomprae3 is null) or (ultcomprae1 > ultcomprae3)) THEN
                ultCompra := cast(extract(day from ultcomprae1) || '/' || extract(month from ultcomprae1) || '/' || extract(year from ultcomprae1) as varchar(10));
                ultFornecedor := ultforne1;
            ELSE
                IF (ultcomprae3 is not null) THEN
                    ultCompra := cast(extract(day from ultcomprae3) || '/' || extract(month from ultcomprae3) || '/' || extract(year from ultcomprae3) as varchar(10));
                    ultFornecedor := ultforne3;             
                END IF;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF ((ultcomprae3 is null) or (ultcomprae2 > ultcomprae3)) THEN
                ultCompra := cast(extract(day from ultcomprae2) || '/' || extract(month from ultcomprae2) || '/' || extract(year from ultcomprae2) as varchar(10));
                ultFornecedor := ultforne2;
            ELSE
                ultCompra := cast(extract(day from ultcomprae3) || '/' || extract(month from ultcomprae3) || '/' || extract(year from ultcomprae3) as varchar(10));
                ultFornecedor := ultforne3;
            END IF;     
        END IF;
    END IF; 

    IF (ultvendae1 is null) THEN
        IF (ultvendae2 is null) THEN
            IF (ultvendae3 is not null) THEN
                ultVenda := cast(extract(day from ultvendae3) || '/' || extract(month from ultvendae3) || '/' || extract(year from ultvendae3) as varchar(10));
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF ((ultvendae3 is null) or (ultvendae2 > ultvendae3)) THEN
                ultVenda := cast(extract(day from ultvendae2) || '/' || extract(month from ultvendae2) || '/' || extract(year from ultvendae2) as varchar(10));
            ELSE
                ultVenda := cast(extract(day from ultvendae3) || '/' || extract(month from ultvendae3) || '/' || extract(year from ultvendae3) as varchar(10));
            END IF;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        IF ((ultvendae2 is null) or (ultvendae1 > ultvendae2)) THEN
            IF ((ultvendae3 is null) or (ultvendae1 > ultvendae3)) THEN
                ultVenda := cast(extract(day from ultvendae1) || '/' || extract(month from ultvendae1) || '/' || extract(year from ultvendae1) as varchar(10));
            ELSE
                IF (ultvendae3 is not null) THEN
                    ultVenda := cast(extract(day from ultvendae3) || '/' || extract(month from ultvendae3) || '/' || extract(year from ultvendae3) as varchar(10));
                END IF;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF ((ultvendae3 is null) or (ultvendae2 > ultvendae3)) THEN
                ultVenda := cast(extract(day from ultvendae2) || '/' || extract(month from ultvendae2) || '/' || extract(year from ultvendae2) as varchar(10));
            ELSE
                ultVenda := cast(extract(day from ultvendae3) || '/' || extract(month from ultvendae3) || '/' || extract(year from ultvendae3) as varchar(10));
            END IF;     
        END IF;
    END IF;     


    vendas = vendase1 + vendase2 + vendase3;
    classeLoja := classee1;

    IF ((qtde1 + qtde2 + qtde3) > ((maximoe1 * vendasdiae1) + (maximoe2 * vendasdiae2) + (maximoe3 * vendasdiae3))) THEN
        sugestao := 0;
    ELSE
        sugestao := cast(((((maximoe1 * vendasdiae1) + (maximoe2 * vendasdiae2) + (maximoe3 * vendasdiae3)) - (qtde1 + qtde2 + qtde3)) + 0.4) as integer);
    END IF;


    RETURN NEXT;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I tried with some query but it got too long, and it isnt even the final query that I need

```
    with suprimento as (
        with vendas as (
            select
                sum(coalesce("quantidade", 0)) as vendas_periodo,
                "inventario_id"
            from
                "WVItens"
            where
                "WVItens"."ultimoDownload" between current_timestamp - (select to_interval(30))
                and current_timestamp and coalesce("status", '') = ''
            group by
                "inventario_id")
        select
            "grade_id",
            "estoque_id",
            sum(cast("quantidadeAtual" as integer)) as "quantidade", 
            sum(cast("vendasPorDia" as integer)) as "vendasPorDia", 
            sum(cast("maximoEmDias" as integer)) as "maximoEmDias", 
            max("dataUltimaVenda") as "ultVenda", 
            max("dataUltimaCompra") as "ultCompra", 
            max("ultimoFornecedor") as "ultFornecedor", 
            sum(cast(vendas_periodo as integer)) as "vendasPeriodo",
            max(coalesce("giro", 0)) as "giro"
        from 
            "Inventarios" 
            left outer join vendas on ("Inventarios"."id" = vendas."inventario_id")
        where 
            coalesce("Inventarios"."status", '') = ''           
        group by
            "grade_id", "estoque_id")
```

NEW EDIT!!!

I tried to make one query only but it is runing until now (passed 800seconds), the query is:

```
WITH suprimento_loja as (
WITH suprimento as (
    WITH vendas as (
      SELECT "inventario_id"
        , SUM(coalesce("quantidade", 0)) as vendas_periodo
      FROM "WVItens" vwi
      WHERE vwi."ultimoDownload" between current_timestamp - (SELECT to_interval(30))
        AND current_timestamp
        AND coalesce("status", '') = ''
      GROUP BY "inventario_id"
    )
    SELECT
        "estoque_id",
        "grade_id",
        "classe" as classe
        , cast("quantidadeAtual" as integer) as qtd
        , cast("vendasPorDia" as integer) as vendasDia
        , cast("maximoEmDias" as integer) as maximo
        , coalesce("dataUltimaVenda", timestamp'01.01.1980') as ultVenda
        , "dataUltimaCompra" as ultCompra
        , "ultimoFornecedor" as ultForn
        , cast(vendas_periodo as integer) as vendas_periodo
        , coalesce("giro", 0) as giro
    FROM "Inventarios"  inv
    LEFT OUTER JOIN vendas ve ON inv."id" = ve."inventario_id"
    )
select
    lo."id" as id,
    e1."grade_id" as grade_id,
    e1.ultVenda,
    case
    when e1.ultVenda > coalesce(e2.ultVenda, timestamp'01.01.1980') and e1.ultVenda > coalesce(e3.ultVenda, timestamp'01.01.1980')
    then e1.ultVenda
    else
        case 
        when coalesce(e2.ultVenda, timestamp'01.01.1980') > coalesce(e3.ultVenda, timestamp'01.01.1980')
        then e2.ultVenda
        else e3.ultVenda
        end
    end as ultVenda,
    case
    when e1.ultCompra > coalesce(e2.ultCompra, timestamp'01.01.1980') and e1.ultCompra > coalesce(e3.ultCompra, timestamp'01.01.1980')
    then e1.ultCompra
    else
        case 
        when coalesce(e2.ultCompra, timestamp'01.01.1980') > coalesce(e3.ultCompra, timestamp'01.01.1980')
        then e2.ultCompra
        else e3.ultCompra
        end
    end as ultCompra,
    case
    when e1.ultCompra > coalesce(e2.ultCompra, timestamp'01.01.1980') and e1.ultCompra > coalesce(e3.ultCompra, timestamp'01.01.1980')
    then e1.ultForn
    else
        case 
        when coalesce(e2.ultCompra, timestamp'01.01.1980') > coalesce(e3.ultCompra, timestamp'01.01.1980')
        then e2.ultForn
        else e3.ultForn
        end
    end as ultForn,
    coalesce(e1.vendas_periodo, 0) + coalesce(e2.vendas_periodo, 0) + coalesce(e3.vendas_periodo, 0) as vendas_periodo,
    e1.classe,
    (coalesce(e1.maximo, 0) * coalesce(e1.vendasDia, 0)) + (coalesce(e2.maximo, 0) * coalesce(e2.vendasDia, 0)) + (coalesce(e3.maximo, 0) * coalesce(e3.vendasDia, 0)) as maximo,
    coalesce(e1.giro, 0) as giro,
    coalesce(e1.qtd, 0) + coalesce(e2.qtd, 0) + coalesce(e3.qtd, 0) as qtde,
    case
        when coalesce(e1.giro, 0) = 0
        then 0
        else
        case 
            when ((coalesce(e1.qtd, 0) + coalesce(e2.qtd, 0) + coalesce(e3.qtd, 0)) > ((coalesce(e1.maximo, 0) * coalesce(e1.vendasDia, 0)) + (coalesce(e2.maximo, 0) * coalesce(e2.vendasDia, 0)) + (coalesce(e3.maximo, 0) * coalesce(e3.vendasDia, 0))))
            then 0
            else cast(((((coalesce(e1.maximo, 0) * coalesce(e1.vendasDia, 0)) + (coalesce(e2.maximo, 0) * coalesce(e2.vendasDia, 0)) + (coalesce(e3.maximo, 0) * coalesce(e3.vendasDia, 0))) 
              - (coalesce(e1.qtd, 0) + coalesce(e2.qtd, 0) + coalesce(e3.qtd, 0))) + 0.4) as integer)
        end 
    end as sugestao
from
    "Lojas" lo
    LEFT OUTER JOIN suprimento e2 ON e2."estoque_id" = lo."estoque2_id"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN suprimento e3 ON e3."estoque_id" = lo."estoque3_id"
    JOIN suprimento e1 ON e1."estoque_id" = lo."estoque1_id")

SELECT
    gr."id",
    sl1.*,
    sl2.*,
    sl3.*,
    sl4.*,
    sl5.*,
    sl6.*
FROM
    "Grades" gr
    JOIN suprimento_loja sl1 ON sl1."grade_id" = gr."id"
    JOIN suprimento_loja sl2 ON sl2."grade_id" = gr."id"
    JOIN suprimento_loja sl3 ON sl3."grade_id" = gr."id"
    JOIN suprimento_loja sl4 ON sl4."grade_id" = gr."id"
    JOIN suprimento_loja sl5 ON sl5."grade_id" = gr."id"
    JOIN suprimento_loja sl6 ON sl6."grade_id" = gr."id"
WHERE
    sl1."id" = 1 AND
    sl2."id" = 2 AND
    sl3."id" = 3 AND
    sl4."id" = 4 AND
    sl5."id" = 5 AND
    sl6."id" = 6
```

I used aliases and join so you can read easly

Comment: What does the function do? Your problem is most probably there, not in the select you are showing us.

Comment: I'll post the function, but it is mostly in portuguese the variables.

Comment: Does this really *need* to be a function with three(?) cursors? Couldn't a join of four(?) tables accomplish the same ? Correction: there are no cursors, only aggregates. Everything could be rewritten into a query or view, IMHO.

Comment: @wildplasser the problem is that this is per store, so it will be 4 joins for each store, and the whole select it get 6 stores, so it would be 24 joins, wich would take a lot longer than it can

Comment: BTW: is this generated code? It looks terrible (no aliases, and everything quoted, no Join-syntax, Brr) It would cost me an hour just to edit it down into a more readable form ...

Comment: @wildplasser I'm just starting to migrate my code from firebird to postgresql, so I'm not so good writing databases codes yet

Comment: There appears to have been put a lot effort into this function. I'll try to strip it down to the bare queries, the code looks too procedural to me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22827/discussion-between-caio-keto-and-wildplasser)

Comment: Looking at the function I do not think your problem is putting the function call into the select list, but executing the function several times. That is your real performance bottleneck.

Comment: A nested CTE and a sixfold join to the same table: you are a fast learner !

Comment: I didnt understand, was that a sarcasm? it takes eternity to execute

Comment: No, it was intended as a compliment!. My conclusion still is: don't use a function, but combine the outer query (SELECT Grades.id ) with the query inside the function (maybe convert that into a view first). This will only involve hardcoding the constants that are now the last but one function parameters, but it will avoid the row-at-a-time processing that the function calling  enforces.

Comment: I tried to make the view like the query, but when I join the (select Grades.id) with the 6 JOINS it still taking a lot of time to execute.   I found out that the problem is that it doesnt use index on Inventarios table, wich takes a lot of cost, but the indexes are created, any tips?

Comment: So I found out that the problem is the "LEFT OUTER JOIN" but as far as I know there isnt another way to do that is there?

Comment: The query is too complex for me to understand, certainly without knowing its intended behaviour. I don't understand why you are joining the same table six times with six different constants. I don't know nothing about your data model keys, or indices, since my crystal boll is in repair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working but in other way.
If someone got some similar problem the solution I got is this:

```
SELECT 
    gr.id,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 1 THEN sl.ultVenda ELSE timestamp'01.01.1980' END) AS ultVenda_l1,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 2 THEN sl.ultVenda ELSE timestamp'01.01.1980' END) AS ultVenda_l2,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 3 THEN sl.ultVenda ELSE timestamp'01.01.1980' END) AS ultVenda_l3,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 4 THEN sl.ultVenda ELSE timestamp'01.01.1980' END) AS ultVenda_l4,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 5 THEN sl.ultVenda ELSE timestamp'01.01.1980' END) AS ultVenda_l5,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 6 THEN sl.ultVenda ELSE timestamp'01.01.1980' END) AS ultVenda_l6,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 1 THEN sl.ultCompra ELSE timestamp'01.01.1980' END) AS ultCompra_l1,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 2 THEN sl.ultCompra ELSE timestamp'01.01.1980' END) AS ultCompra_l2,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 3 THEN sl.ultCompra ELSE timestamp'01.01.1980' END) AS ultCompra_l3,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 4 THEN sl.ultCompra ELSE timestamp'01.01.1980' END) AS ultCompra_l4,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 5 THEN sl.ultCompra ELSE timestamp'01.01.1980' END) AS ultCompra_l5,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 6 THEN sl.ultCompra ELSE timestamp'01.01.1980' END) AS ultCompra_l6,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 1 THEN sl.ultForn ELSE '' END) AS ultForn_l1,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 2 THEN sl.ultForn ELSE '' END) AS ultForn_l2,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 3 THEN sl.ultForn ELSE '' END) AS ultForn_l3,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 4 THEN sl.ultForn ELSE '' END) AS ultForn_l4,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 5 THEN sl.ultForn ELSE '' END) AS ultForn_l5,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 6 THEN sl.ultForn ELSE '' END) AS ultForn_l6,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 1 THEN sl.vendas_periodo ELSE 0 END) AS vendas_periodo_l1,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 2 THEN sl.vendas_periodo ELSE 0 END) AS vendas_periodo_l2,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 3 THEN sl.vendas_periodo ELSE 0 END) AS vendas_periodo_l3,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 4 THEN sl.vendas_periodo ELSE 0 END) AS vendas_periodo_l4,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 5 THEN sl.vendas_periodo ELSE 0 END) AS vendas_periodo_l5,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 6 THEN sl.vendas_periodo ELSE 0 END) AS vendas_periodo_l6,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 1 THEN sl.maximo ELSE 0 END) AS maximo_l1,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 2 THEN sl.maximo ELSE 0 END) AS maximo_l2,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 3 THEN sl.maximo ELSE 0 END) AS maximo_l3,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 4 THEN sl.maximo ELSE 0 END) AS maximo_l4,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 5 THEN sl.maximo ELSE 0 END) AS maximo_l5,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 6 THEN sl.maximo ELSE 0 END) AS maximo_l6,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 1 THEN sl.giro ELSE 0 END) AS giro_l1,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 2 THEN sl.giro ELSE 0 END) AS giro_l2,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 3 THEN sl.giro ELSE 0 END) AS giro_l3,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 4 THEN sl.giro ELSE 0 END) AS giro_l4,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 5 THEN sl.giro ELSE 0 END) AS giro_l5,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 6 THEN sl.giro ELSE 0 END) AS giro_l6,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 1 THEN sl.qtde ELSE 0 END) AS qtd_l1,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 2 THEN sl.qtde ELSE 0 END) AS qtd_l2,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 3 THEN sl.qtde ELSE 0 END) AS qtd_l3,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 4 THEN sl.qtde ELSE 0 END) AS qtd_l4,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 5 THEN sl.qtde ELSE 0 END) AS qtd_l5,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 6 THEN sl.qtde ELSE 0 END) AS qtd_l6,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 1 THEN sl.sugestao ELSE 0 END) AS sugestao_l1,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 2 THEN sl.sugestao ELSE 0 END) AS sugestao_l2,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 3 THEN sl.sugestao ELSE 0 END) AS sugestao_l3,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 4 THEN sl.sugestao ELSE 0 END) AS sugestao_l4,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 5 THEN sl.sugestao ELSE 0 END) AS sugestao_l5,
    max(CASE sl.id WHEN 6 THEN sl.sugestao ELSE 0 END) AS sugestao_l6
FROM "Grades" gr
INNER JOIN suprimento_loja sl ON sl.grade_id = gr.id
group by gr.id
order by gr.id
```

And the view 'suprimento_loja' is that query used before in the function.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do now to speed up the query - remake the function to take less time.

It PostgreSQL 9.3 you will be able to use your second query variant with `LATERAL`, but it wont be significantly faster.

Comment: It's impossible to work like that, it took more than 1000 seconds to query, any changes in the function will not speed a lot. So basically I need to make the query in another way?

Comment: @CaioKeto Yes. You need to find another solution. No matter how you call the function, it will still be executed for every `Grades.id`. The problem is in the function itself.

Comment: But if I do this all in the query, it will be slower than the function, Is there any good solution for this problem? Cause I need to make calculations in the function and join 3 selects.

Comment: @CaioKeto Generally functions are slower, then the queries. Especially when you need to `JOIN` it with something.

Answer (score 0):

This is only the edited body (untested, hope I didn't make any typos ;-):

```
WITH vendas as (
  SELECT "inventario_id"
      , SUM(coalesce("quantidade", 0)) as vendas_periodo
  FROM "WVItens" vwi
  WHERE vwi."ultimoDownload" between current_timestamp - (SELECT to_interval(vendas_dias)) AND current_timestamp
    AND coalesce("status", '') = ''
  GROUP BY "inventario_id"
)
SELECT into qtde1, vendasdiae1, maximoe1, ultvendae1, ultcomprae1, ultforne1, classee1, vendase1, giroe1
    cast("quantidadeAtual" as integer)
    , cast("vendasPorDia" as integer)
    , cast("maximoEmDias" as integer)
    , "dataUltimaVenda"
    , "dataUltimaCompra"
    , "ultimoFornecedor"
    , "classe"
    , cast(vendas_periodo as integer)
    , coalesce("giro", 0)
FROM "Inventarios" inv
JOIN "Lojas" lo ON inv."estoque_id" = lo."estoque1_id"
JOIN vendas ve ON inv."id" = ve."inventario_id"
WHERE coalesce( inv."status", '') = ''
 AND lo."id" = lojaId
 AND "grade_id" = gradeId
   ;

WITH vendas as (
  SELECT "inventario_id"
      , SUM(coalesce("quantidade", 0)) as vendas_periodo
  FROM "WVItens" vwi
  WHERE vwi."ultimoDownload" between current_timestamp - (SELECT to_interval(vendas_dias))
      AND current_timestamp
      AND coalesce("status", '') = ''
  GROUP BY "inventario_id"
)
SELECT into qtde2, vendasdiae2, maximoe2, ultvendae2, ultcomprae2, ultforne2, vendase2, giroe2
    cast("quantidadeAtual" as integer)
    , cast("vendasPorDia" as integer)
    , cast("maximoEmDias" as integer)
    , "dataUltimaVenda"
    , "dataUltimaCompra"
    , "ultimoFornecedor"
    , cast(vendas_periodo as integer)
    , coalesce("giro", 0)
FROM "Inventarios" inv
JOIN "Lojas" lo ON inv."estoque_id" = lo."estoque2_id"
JOIN vendas ve ON inv."id" = vendas."inventario_id"
WHERE coalesce( inv."status", '') = ''
  AND lo."id" = lojaId
  AND "grade_id" = gradeId
    ;

WITH vendas as (
  SELECT "inventario_id"
    , SUM(coalesce("quantidade", 0)) as vendas_periodo
  FROM "WVItens" vwi
  WHERE vwi."ultimoDownload" between current_timestamp - (SELECT to_interval(vendas_dias))
    AND current_timestamp
    AND coalesce("status", '') = ''
  GROUP BY "inventario_id"
)
SELECT into qtde3, vendasdiae3, maximoe3, ultvendae3, ultcomprae3, ultforne3, vendase3, giroe3
    cast("quantidadeAtual" as integer)
    , cast("vendasPorDia" as integer)
    , cast("maximoEmDias" as integer)
    , "dataUltimaVenda"
    , "dataUltimaCompra"
    , "ultimoFornecedor"
    , cast(vendas_periodo as integer)
    , coalesce("giro", 0)
FROM "Inventarios"  inv
JOIN "Lojas" lo ON inv."estoque_id" = lo."estoque2_id"
JOIN vendas ve ON inv."id" = vendas."inventario_id"
WHERE coalesce( inv."status", '') = ''
  AND lo."id" = lojaId
  AND "grade_id" = gradeId
    ;
```

At first glance, It appears you are doing exactly the same query three times, with different constants, which to me looks subobtimate.

Comment: The diference is that the first one it gets from the first inventory of the store, but I need the 3 inventorys to make the calculations. is there any best way to make it?

Comment: I'm still staring at the code. It looks too procedural. My gut feeling is that it could all be combined into one query.

Comment: I'm trying to make one unique query too, but I don't think I can with a fast return

Comment: I tried based on what you did here, making one query to return all that I need, but it takes a LOT to execute it passed over 1000seconds and didnt finish yet.

Comment: My "answer" made no changes to the query, I only edited it into a more readable form (I could have made some errors, since I have no data to test it against). Your update again seems to avoid the join-syntax and aliases, making it unreadable again.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not used to make this join-sytax and aliases. I just tried to use your "readable" query to make it in one big query to return all without functions

Comment: I changed there, take a look